# Closing gzip writer in defer causes data loss

Tags: go

I use golang `gzip.NewWriter` to zip a slice，and `defer Close()` to close the writer. But when reading from the zipped data, It will return `unexpected EOF`. The code is:

```
func main() {

    a := []byte{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}
    zippedData, err := zipData(a)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    unzippedData, err := unzipData(zippedData)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", unzippedData)

}
```

The zip function is:

```
func zipData(originData []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    var bf bytes.Buffer
    gw := gzip.NewWriter(&bf)

    defer gw.Close()

    _, err := gw.Write(originData)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("gzip data err: %v", err))
    }

    err = gw.Flush()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // if I rm 'defer gw.Close()' and call 'gw.Close()' here, it'll be ok

    logs.Debug("before gzip len: %v", len(originData))
    logs.Debug("gzip len: %v", bf.Len())
    return bf.Bytes(), nil
}
```

Above zip function uses `defer gw.Close()` to close gw.

The unzip function is:

```
func unzipData(zippedData []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    dst := make([]byte, len(zippedData))
    copy(dst, zippedData)

    reader, err := gzip.NewReader(bytes.NewBuffer(dst))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("unzip err :%v", err))
    }

    defer reader.Close()

    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("read err :%v", err))
    }
    return data, err
}
```

Why `defer gw.Close()` cases `unexpected EOF`?

Answer (score 8):

With defer, you're missing the gzip footer. According to the `Close` docs:

> Close closes the Writer by flushing any unwritten data to the underlying io.Writer and writing the GZIP footer. It does not close the underlying io.Writer.

So even though `Flush` flushes any buffered data, it doesn't write the footer. With a deferred close, you get the byte array that doesn't contain the footer and return it, and then the footer is written to the output.

Close the writer before returning.

Answer (score 4):

With `defer`, `gw.Close()` runs after the `bf.Bytes()` call in the return statement. To make sure complete content is returned, you should explicitly call `gw.Close` before trying to read bytes from the buffer.

The simplest fix for your code is to replace the `Flush` call with a `Close` call. `Flush` is for when you are not done writing, but in your case you've already finished compressing, so calling `Close` should be enough.