# Defer gzip.Close() doesn't write the footer

Tags: go

I am trying to use `gzip.NewWriter` to stream data in and write compressed data to a CSV file. Everything works except the footer doesn't seem to get written when I use `defer gzip.Close()`. I get an `Unexpected end of data` message when I try to open the file with 7-zip.

**Note**: I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923654/closing-gzip-writer-in-defer-causes-data-loss) (and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60923694/2755165)) but I feel like my problem is a little different, because I am writing to a file and not returning the bytes.

As I understand it, OP in that question was returning the bytes *before* writing the footer. But because I am just writing to a file, I shouldn't be running into the same issue.

Here is a snippet of my code. I have removed all error-checking for the sake of brevity.

```
// Worker that reads invoices and compresses them into a single file.
func compressWorker(c Config, archived <-chan Invoice, done chan<- int) {
    now := time.Now().Format("2006-01")
    path := filepath.Join(c.OutDir, now+".csv.gz")

    readColumns := false

    f, _ := os.Create(path)
    defer closeWriter("csv file", f)

    cw := gzip.NewWriter(f)
    cw.Name = now + ".csv"

    // * This is where I originally had my defer Close call.
    // defer closeWriter("compression stream", cw)

    for i := range archived {
        if !readColumns {
            b := []byte(i.CsvColumns() + ",DateLastSaved\n")
            cw.Write(b)
            readColumns = true
        }

        b := []byte(i.ToCsvString() + "," + time.Now().Format("2006-01-02") + "\n")
        cw.Write(b)
    }

    // Ordinarily I'd say we defer this earlier, but that doesn't work for some
    // reason.
    closeWriter("compression writer", cw)

    done <- 1
}

// Print an error with a prefix string and exit.
func HandleErrorWithPrefix(e error, p string) {
    if e != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error: %v; %v\n", p, e)
    }
}

func closeWriter(n string, wc io.WriteCloser) {
    log.Printf("closing %v\n", n)
    err := wc.Close()
    HandleErrorWithPrefix(err, fmt.Sprintf("error closing writer '%v'", n))
}
```

Interestingly, I get this from `closeWriter` with my original code and deferred closing:

```
2021/10/13 09:05:42 closing compression writer
2021/10/13 09:05:42 closing csv file
```

However, I get this when I close `cw` *without* deferring:

```
2021/10/13 09:06:01 closing compression stream
```

I get no errors in `closeWriter` though so I'm not sure why the file wouldn't be closing. Deferred works last-in-first-out right?

Comment: Don't forget to [`Flush()`](https://pkg.go.dev/compress/gzip@go1.17.1#Writer.Flush). And you may want to call [`Sync()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os@go1.17.1#File.Sync) before closing the file as well.

Comment: There's a difference between your 2 code. Your original with `defer`: it first sends on `done`, and then closes the gzip writer then the file. Your modified code without `defer`: it first closes the gzip writer, then sends on `done`, and then it would try to close the file. How are you calling `compressWorker()`? What is the purpose of `done`?

Comment: I call `compressWorker()` in a goroutine from `main`. `done` is used to tell main that I'm done compressing. I have other goroutines, but `compressWorker()` should almost always be the last to run. Then main would end.

Comment: I just tried `cw.Flush()` and `f.Sync()` just before `done <- 1`, but still had the same problem.

Comment: hm I think I see it now. If I put a `log.Printf` at the *end* of `closeWriter()` I never see that message. So I think the problem is that after I send to `done`, `closeWriter()` never gets to actually finish.

Comment: Remember that `done <- 1` will be executed *before* any `defer`ed function calls.

Comment: If your `main()` ends once you send a value on `done`, then your app terminates, it does not wait for other goroutines to finish! This explains the difference. Sending a value on `done` should be the last thing `compressWorker()` does, it should be in a function first deferred! And not the last statement of `compressWorker()`, because deferred functions only run after that!

Comment: According to your code, the deferred closing version prints `closing compression stream`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears my problem wasn't much different: my program was ending before my writers had enough time to fully close.

I solved this, with the help of everyone commenting, by moving my `done` send to a deferred closure at the beginning of the worker function.

```
func compressWorker(c Config, archived <-chan Invoice, done chan<- int) {
    // Defer here ensures it will always be run last.
    defer func() {
        done <- 1
    }()

    // ...

    defer f.Close()
    defer cw.Close()

    // ...
}
```